# Weird batch file 'start' command behaviour

Tags: batch-file, console-application

I'm used to run my tasks one after another in batch file, for example:

```
start /B /WAIT /D D:\...\1 /low D:\...\Release\SC.exe
start /B /WAIT /D D:\...\2 /low D:\...\Release\SC.exe
start /B /WAIT /D D:\...\3 /low D:\...\Release\SC.exe
...
```

First path is the working directory, the second one is path to the source file, which is a simple console application fed with some input from the working directory and outputting some text files to the working directory. At my home computer, the console runs each program in a new window and waits for it to finish and then run another etc. For that reason, the program outputs information in the new window and I can clearly see the progress etc. However, at my work computer, the batch file runs the console program in the very same console window and the output gets messed up (it basically rewrites itself, ignoring endl and \b), see the following screenshot:
[image: Batch file problem]

How can I tell the batch file to run a console exe application in separate windows (and then close it after it finishes)? Alternatively, how can I make it not ignore endlines in cout so it won't rewrite itself? I would rather prefer opening a new window instead of stacking up output from several application runs in the same window...

EDIT: running win 10 on both machines

Comment: what if you try like this: `start "" /B /WAIT /D "D:\...\3" /low "D:\...\Release\SC.exe"` ?

Comment: Nah, it does the same thing as before...

Comment: What about not using the `/B` option?

Comment: @Compo that works, but why does the console mess the output up so much if told not to open another window?

Comment: It might be a carriage return/line feed sequence issue, or even some unicode problem. Add to that the console obviously wraps the excessively long lines and you could get strange looking output, I suppose.

Comment: Well, it looked like it stacked several lines to one with random line-breaking (instead of the one that breaks where intended)...in any case, removing /B solves the issue. (Y)